# polite synonym for obnoxious behavior

Tags: expressions

Looking for a polite/coherent way to convey someone's behavior who "copies" another person, or is "up their ass" a lot

Comment: Exactly what kind of person/behaviour are you asking about? Note that apart from the fact that they're both derogatory, someone who *"copies" another person* and someone who's *"up their ass" a lot* have no real semantic connection.

Comment: I'm actually having a bit of trouble with the "up their ass" metaphor.  Is this describing someone whom a more polite generation would call a "brown noser"?

Comment: a copycat. What else?

Answer (score 2):

***sycophantic*** comes to mind. From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sycophantic):

> Behaving or done in an obsequious way in order to gain advantage

*Example:*

> I guess some people thought I was a creep, offering sycophantic praise
>   of someone who happens to be my boss

Also try [flattering](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flattering?q=flattering%20) or [fawning](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fawning).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with ***obsequious***

*Obedient or attentive to an excessive or servile degree:*

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsequious